# Organizing a CSV file with JSON datat

Tags: java, json, csv

I am trying to populate a CSV file with json data, but I need to organize everything a certain way. I need the json keys to be headers and the associated values be the data under it, but the way the json is set up I can populate names in one, but the info in another block labeled "items" needs to be split up among multiple cells with keys being the header and the values populating the table. I do not know how to split up individual components of a json block into its own cells.

So CSV should be set up like:

```
headers:       name            item1     item2    item3
data cells:    [first last]   [value1]  [value2] [value3]
```

JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "info":[
     {
       "name":{
        "first" : -----
        "last":-----
     },
   "item": [
    {
      "item1" : "value1"
      "item2" : "value2"
      "item3" : "value3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have used the Apache commons FileUtils.writeStringToFile, but that writes all the "items" keys and values in one cell, I need 1 item to 1 cell. The name is fine because the components can go in one cell, I just need to split up the items.

The result so far is Name is one header and the cell under that header has first and last name, the second header is Items and lists all keys and values in that json block in that one cell. 
I expect the items keys to be the header and the values under those and split up.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: To clarify I am pulling the JSON data from a URL so the way it is written is the way it is. I can not change it.

Comment: modify`"item": [
    {
      "item1" : "value1"
      "item2" : "value2"
      "item3" : "value3"
    }` to be `"item": [
      {"item1" : "value1"},
      {"item2" : "value2"},
      {"item3" : "value3"}` and try again.

Comment: sorry I should mention that I am pulling the JSON from a URL so I can not edit it or change the way it is written.

Comment: When you got the JSON in your procedure,you can make a new local json that with the given format use the JSON data that you pulled from the url.Or you just anaylis the JSON manually to get the data you want and use stream to write it to the csv file is also ok.

Comment: could you show example code please for the second solution you said?

Comment: I add a answer ,you can see what i do as the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JSONObject  jo = (JSONObject) JSONObject.parse("{\"info\":[{\"name\":{\"first\" : \"-----\",\"last\":\"-----\"},\"item\": [{\"item1\" : \"value1\",\"item2\" : \"value2\",\"item3\" : \"value3\"}]}]}");
        String line1 = "headers:\tname\titem1\titem2\titem3\n";
        String line2 = "data cells:";
        JSONArray  info = jo.getJSONArray("info");
        JSONObject info1 = info.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject name = info1.getJSONObject("name");
        String nameKeys = name.keySet().toString();
        JSONArray item = info1.getJSONArray("item");
        JSONObject firstItem = item.getJSONObject(0);
        String item1Value = firstItem.getString("item1");
        String item2Value = firstItem.getString("item2");
        String item3Value = firstItem.getString("item3");
        line2 = line2 + "\t" +nameKeys + "\t"+ item1Value +"\t"+item2Value+"\t"+item3Value+"\n";
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test.csv"));
        bw.write(line1);
        bw.write(line2);
        bw.close();

    }
```

just look like this ,get the value and write them to the csv file.
Another way you can use regex like `(?<=item\d"\s:\s").*?(?=")` to match the "value1","value2","value3" and regex `item\d` mathches "item1","item2","item3" to cut out the json string to get the value.

Comment: ok i tried to do the parse, but it does not let me. Do you have a certain external jar added?

Comment: I foggot it ,I used `fastjson` to parse it.The other json parsed jar such as `gson` can also parse the json as the same  reason.

Comment: Ok show me exactly what  you did to include the parse() method, because I have been so confused on how to parse json. Everytime I have tried it I end up with errors and it does not work

Comment: **First**,you should make the style of json correctly，you can use a parse josn website to verify. **Second**,if your json string is short,you can edit it in a text editor by replacing all `"` with `\"` because `"` in java string should be transferred meaning. **Another way**,if your json string is to long and you don't want to use it in java directly,you can put it in a text file and use java stream to read the josn from the file,this way do not need to use `\\`  for transterred meaning.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class JsonToCsv {

public static void main(String args[]) throws JSONException, IOException
{
    List<JSONObject> infoList=new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    JSONObject info=new JSONObject();
    JSONObject name=new JSONObject();
    name.put("first", "John");
    name.put("last","Doe");
    info.put("name",name );

    List<JSONObject> itemList=new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    JSONObject item1=new JSONObject();
    JSONObject item2=new JSONObject();
    item1.put("item1", "val1");
    itemList.add(item1);
    item2.put("item2", "val2");
    itemList.add(item2);


    info.put("item", itemList);
    infoList.add(info);

    System.out.println(infoList);
    convertJsonToCsv(infoList);

}

public static void convertJsonToCsv(List<JSONObject> infoList) throws IOException, JSONException {

    FileWriter csvWriter = new FileWriter("InfoFile.csv"); 
    List<String> header= new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0;i<infoList.size();i++) {

        JSONObject info_obj=infoList.get(i);
        Iterator<String> info_keys=info_obj.keys();
        while(info_keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = info_keys.next();

            if (info_obj.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {

                JSONObject obj=info_obj.getJSONObject(key);
                Iterator<String> obj_keys=obj.keys();
                while(obj_keys.hasNext()) {
                    String k=obj_keys.next();
                    if(i==0)
                        header.add(k);
                    values.add(obj.getString(k));
                }

            }
            if (info_obj.get(key) instanceof JSONArray) {


                JSONArray item_array=info_obj.getJSONArray(key);
                for(int j=0;j<item_array.length();j++) {

                    JSONObject item=item_array.getJSONObject(j);
                    Iterator<String> item_keys=item.keys();
                    while(item_keys.hasNext()) {
                        String k=item_keys.next();
                        if(i==0)
                            header.add(k);
                        values.add(item.getString(k));
                    }
                }

            }

        }


    }

    for(String head : header) {

        csvWriter.append(head);  
        csvWriter.append(","); 
    }
    csvWriter.append("\n");

    for(int m=0;m<values.size();m++) {


        csvWriter.append(values.get(m)); 
        if((m+1)%(header.size())==0) {

            csvWriter.append("\n"); 
        }
        else {
            csvWriter.append(","); 
        }

    }
    csvWriter.flush();


}
```

}